# Is there a method for making a MainWindow windows taskbar icon blink?

Tags: c++, windows, qt5

I am designing an application which needs to be able to get the user's attention. I play a ding sound and open up a notification dialog window, but I would also like the application's taskbar icon to flash the way that an installer that needs your permission does.

This is for a Windows 7 application, although I would prefer a cross-platform solution if one is available. Other resources I've seen suggest that that should be a side effect of using `QWidget::show()`, however I have not been able to reproduce this.

I expect the taskbar icon to look like this windows explorer notification telling me it has a conflict while copying files:

[image: Windows 7 Taskbar icon flashing]

Comment: You may be looking for [`FlashWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindow) or [`FlashWindowEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindowex). I don't know of a Qt wrapper for those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In windows, you should use [`FlashWindowEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindowex) function which takes [`FLASHWINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-flashwinfo) strcuture as argument with which you can control parameters like how long to flash, flash interval, what to flash(taskbar, window) etc..

---

For Qt, refer [`void QApplication::alert(QWidget *widget, int msec = 0);`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#alert)

Comment: This worked! For anyone else viewing this, I put the following in the body of a method of my `MainWindow`: `qApp->alert(this, 0);`